# Group Rows in a variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have our client data in following format :

```
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>HEAD 1</th>
    <th>HEAD 2</th>     
    <th>HEAD 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp1">
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp2">
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
<tr id="Grp3">
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>...
</table>
```

And have to move the rows up and down depends upon some condition. Here is my js code:

```
if(val == valX){
 $("#Grp2").after($("#Grp1"))// This will hold only one tr.
 // move all Grp1 data rows and set after Grp2 data
}
if(val == valy){

 // move all Grp2 data rows on the top of all the rows
}

if(val == valz){
 // move all Grp3 data rows on the top of all the rows
}...
```

Since my question is:

- How can I move all three rows at a time up or down OR
- How can I get group of 3 rows in a variable like `combined = $("#Grp1") + $("#Grp1").next() + $("#Grp1").next();`

**Note**- As the Html structure is also used for some other purposes. Since I can not change any structure in the HTML

Comment: You could use `<tbody>` to group the rows and then apply your logic.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree with you. It's a kind of a hack, that's why I put it as a comment.

Comment: @ReCaptcha that will only work if the rows are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Moving rows up or down made me look into sorting, so I hope you find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906760/jquery-sort-table-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to a jQuery collection:

```
var combined = $("#Grp1").add($("#Grp1").nextUntil("#Grp2"));
```

An equivalent way is with `.addBack`:

```
var combined = $("#Grp1").nextUntil("#Grp2").addBack();
```

Comment: @Barmar- Many Thanks for your efforts. Worked like a charm!! :)

Comment: Why not using `addBack`?

Comment: @Vohuman I'm not sure what the effective difference is between them.

Comment: You are right. There is no fundamental difference. As you have used `nextUntil` I think `addBack` is just more readable.