# JQuery select elements with custom attributes

Tags: jquery, html

Further to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687911/group-rows-in-a-variable), I have to select all the rows whose display-order is not "-1".

```
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>HEAD 1</th>
    <th>HEAD 2</th>     
    <th>HEAD 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp1" display-order="0">
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp2" display-order="-1">
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
<tr id="Grp3" display-order="0">
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>...
</table>
```

My Question is:

- How can I select all `<tr>`s having `display-order`, but the `display-order` should not be -1?
- I know that I can use  `.not( "[display-order='-1']" )`, But I'm not getting how can I get `tr` with any `display-order`?

  ```
  $("[display-order='What_Value_Would_Go_Here?']").not("[display-order='-1']");
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to loop over using `.each()` and check the custom attribute of each selected element.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$("[display-order]").each(function(item){
  if($(this).attr('display-order') !== '-1')
    console.log('found');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>HEAD 1</th>
    <th>HEAD 2</th>     
    <th>HEAD 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp1" display-order="0">
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>      
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp2" display-order="-1">
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>      
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
<tr id="Grp3" display-order="0">
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>      
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, This solution give me the exact idea about how to do.

Comment: @trex I am glad it helps. Readup: [Attribute Selector | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [.each() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/). I would appreciate an upvote too. ;)

Comment: @trex Also note that it would be more appropriate if you use data attributes if you want custom attributes. Readup: [Data Attributes | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). All you need to do is replace `display-order` by `data-display-order`. Your code will be then more readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#t01 tr[display-order][display-order!=-1]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$("tr[display-order]tr[display-order!='-1']");
```

It will select all `tr` elements that have the attribute `display-order` and where the `display-order` attribute does not equal -1.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdxc7kr/)

References: 
[Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) 
[Attribute Not Equal To Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)