# Get next all inputs after second textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Variable in my javascript assume `var oneTR= $("#Grp1");`, And I can combine group of 3 TRs to a `Combined` Row  using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687911/group-rows-in-a-variable).

What I want is:

- Get all the `inputs` after second `textarea` in one combined row

  ```
   <table id="t01">
    <tr>
      <th>HEAD 1</th>
      <th>HEAD 2</th>
      <th>HEAD 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Grp1">
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
      <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grp1 data</td>
      <td><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Grp2">
      <td>Grp2 data</td>
      <td>Grp2 data</td>
      <td>Grp2 data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grp2 data</td>
      <td>Grp2 data</td>
      <td><textarea></textarea><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Grp3">
      <td>Grp3 data</td>
      <td>Grp3 data</td>
      <td>Grp3 data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grp3 data</td>
      <td>Grp3 data</td>
      <td><textarea></textarea><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

I tried solution like this:

```
 var finalinps = oneTR.add(oneTR.nextUntil("#Grp2")).find("textarea").eq(1).nextAll(":input");

 console.log("finalinps: ", finalinps.length); //finalinps: 0
```

but this is not working. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7dbuyfn/)

**Note** - I'm getting proper `textarea` with this line but not just `inputs`

```
oneTR.add(oneTR.nextUntil("#Grp2")).find("textarea").eq(1)
```

Comment: Depending on the DOM structure so heavily results in a brittle solution. Better to identify the required elements using a class value or similar. BTW, what library are you using? Add a tag for it.

Comment: @RobG - I'm using  jQuery

Comment: What is your expected input count?

Comment: Detach the inputs and insertAfter the 2nd textarea.

Comment: @MangeshParte -here from the html, 5 inputs.

Comment: Consider using a table section to identify the controls you want to get, then you could do something like: `$('#sectionID input')`.

Comment: @Slime - I'm not getting your solution, can you pls explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7dbuyfn/2/)**

```
oneTR.add(oneTR.nextUntil("#Grp2")).find("textarea").eq(1).parents('tr').find('input');
console.log("finalinps: ", finalinps.length);
```

Comment: -Sorry - I wanted 6 textareas. That was my mistake! In case of first group of rows there will be 5!

Answer (score 2):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
// updated to return `oneTR1 , 6 `input elements` following second `textarea`
var finalinps = oneTR.add($("#t01 input").filter(function(i, el) {
                    return $("#t01 textarea:eq(1)").parents("tr").index() >=  
                           $(el).parents("tr").index()})
                );
```

```js
var oneTR = $("#Grp1");

//var finalinps = oneTR.add(oneTR.nextUntil("#Grp2")).find("textarea").eq(1).nextAll(":input");



var finalinps = oneTR.add($("#t01 input").filter(function(i, el) {
  return $("#t01 textarea:eq(1)").parents("tr").index() >= $(el).parents("tr").index()
}));

console.log("finalinps: ", finalinps.length, finalinps);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>HEAD 1</th>
    <th>HEAD 2</th>
    <th>HEAD 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp1">
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp1 data</td>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp2">
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>Grp2 data</td>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Grp3">
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>Grp3 data</td>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: :- Thanks! I think this is what I want but, this will work for only  first group of TR. I wonder it won't work if `var oneTR = $("#Grp2");`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of text input elements next to the 2nd text area with the below js:

```
//get the index of 2nd textarea tr
var curIndex = $("table textarea:eq(1)").closest("tr").index();

//get the length of text input elements
var txtlen = $("table tr:eq("+curIndex+")").nextAll('tr').andSelf().find("input[type=text]").length;

alert(txtlen);
```

Demo Link: http://jsfiddle.net/84wk1kry/2/