# Adding a row and sorting table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I am running into a very small issue which has taken more than two hours.

What I want is to insert a row in an HTML table and then sort it in ascending order. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22906760/1050256) and thought that I can get this simple task working, but in vein.

Here is my little form and table:

```html
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
Status: <input type="text" name="status" id="status">><br>
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,document.getElementsByName('status')[0].value)">Click</button><br><br>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Doe, John</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa, John</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My inline JavaScript function looks like this:

```js
function myFunction(name, status) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = status;

    // The following code should sort the table.
    var tbody = $('#mytable').find('tbody');
    tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    }).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

*Please note that adding a row to the table works fine, it just adds it to the top.*

There are **no** console errors. The code which (apparently) should sort the table does not do anything. I've the subset of my HTML [here on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju7dB/222/), and yes that works fine.

---

I know about [jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin but do not need to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This selector:

```
$('#mytable')
```

...is incorrect. Your table's ID is `myTable`, and IDs are case-sensitive. [Here's a working version of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/mfc3nq07/) with that fix.